# Why does a test fail when using findBy but succeed when using waitfor?

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-redux, redux-saga, react-testing-library

Using react-testing-library, the following test works:

```
it( 'renders popular search terms, with links to search urls', () => {
      waitFor(() => {
        const popularSearch = screen.getByText( Copywriting.buyer.shop.popularSearch, {}, { timeout: 5000 })
        expect( popularSearch ).toBeInTheDocument()

        const popularSearchPills = screen.findAllByTestId( 'pill' )
        expect( popularSearchPills.length ).toBeGreaterThan( 0 )

        const hrefs = popularSearchPills.map( pill => pill.href )
        expect( hrefs.filter( urlIsValidAndNotBaseUrl )).not.toHaveLength( 0 )
      })
    })
```

But the following test used to work, but now fails:

```
it( 'renders popular search terms, with links to search urls', async () => {
      const popularSearch = await screen.findByText( Copywriting.buyer.shop.popularSearch )
      expect( popularSearch ).toBeInTheDocument()

      const popularSearchPills = await screen.findAllByTestId( 'pill' )
      expect( popularSearchPills.length ).toBeGreaterThan( 0 )

      const hrefs = popularSearchPills.map( pill => pill.href )
      expect( hrefs.filter( urlIsValidAndNotBaseUrl )).not.toHaveLength( 0 )
    })
```

Why would the two code snippets function differently? I thought findby was supposed to be a wrapper for waitfor.

Note: what's happening under the hood of the rendered component is that we dispatch an action which calls a saga, the saga calls `fetch`, which returns a piece of data, the saga then calls another action with the data as a payload, triggering a reducer that saves the data to the store. The view should then update to include the element with `Copywriting.buyer.shop.popularSearch`.

Is there any reason, *on principle*, why the two tests should have different outputs?

Comment: By the look of it, seems fine (except for using the find query inside waitFor). Try adding logs at every step of the execution that you expect.

Comment: I've got the same problem and this is the 2nd post I encountered about this problem. Did you ever find the reason or solution?

Answer (score 12):

That could be because the default timeout is 1000ms (https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#findby) while in your first test you manually specify a 5000ms timeout.

You will also notice in the docs that the `findBy*` methods accept the `waitForOptions` as their third argument.

So you should

```js
const popularSearch = await screen.findByText(Copywriting.buyer.shop.popularSearch, undefined, {
  timeout: 5000
});
```

Now the two tests would be identical.

Comment: Have tried using 5000ms timeout on both, results the same

Comment: What is that timeout function you're using? I can't find that pattern in the docs.

Comment: @C.T.Bell read https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#findby-queries

Comment: I've read the docs you linked to. They only show `timeout` being used for as a parameter on `waitFor` not `findByx`. When I tried passing it to `findByx`, I got an error that it was not a function, or something like that.

Comment: @C.T.Bell  I quote "`findBy` methods are a combination of `getBy` queries and `waitFor`. They accept the `waitFor` options as the last argument (*e.g. `await screen.findByText('text', queryOptions, waitForOptions)`*)".

Answer (score 2):

Even if you use the `waitForOptions` it still fails. Had this quote from Kent who is the creator of this testing library [Using waitFor to wait for elements that can be queried with find*](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#using-waitfor-to-wait-for-elements-that-can-be-queried-with-find)

Mind the word "**can**". I think its better to use `waitFor` than `findBy` which is in my opinion is more self explanatory that it is async/needs to be waited `waitFor` than `findBy`.